# Extract a part of the string based on a pattern C#

Tags: c#, string, pattern-matching, extract

I'm  trying to extract a part of a string in C# based on the specific pattern.

Examples :

> pattern1 => string1_string2_**{0}**_string3_string4.txt should return string value of
> "{0}"
>
> ```
>  toto_tata_2021_titi_tutu.txt should return 2021
> ```

> pattern2 => string1_string2_string3_**{0}**_string4.csv should return string value of "{0}"

> ```
>  toto_tata_titi_2022_tutu.csv should return 2022
> ```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you could just split on the underscore and take the 3rd or 4th value.  Or maybe you need to look at using regular expressions.  Or are you saying you literally have to use the patterns you've shown?

Comment: I need a method that does this automatically when I pass the pattern to it, knowing that the position of the desired string can change in the pattern as indicated above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the library `System.Text.RegularExpressions`:

```
public static string ExtractYear(string s)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(s, "([0-9]{8}" +
                               "|[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" +
                               "|[0-9]{4})");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        return match.Groups[1].Value;
    }
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

I added the solution for the new case. You can add more patterns by appending them with a '|'.

Mind the order of your patterns. The first gets matched first for every character in your string.
For Situations like that Regex sound like a great Option.

Comment: input: "toto_tata_2021_titi_tutu.txt" \ output: "2021"

Comment: This doesn't cover all cases, i can have toto_tata_2021-10-05_2022-11-20_15-13-10.txt and it should return 2021-10-05

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @n4tri : it works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
string pattern = "string1_string2_{0}_string3_string4.txt";
int indexOfPlaceholder = pattern.IndexOf("{0}");
int numberOfPreviousUnderscores = pattern.Substring(0, indexOfPlaceholder).Split('_', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
string stringToBeMatched = "toto_tata_2021_titi_tutu.txt";
string stringAtPlaceholder = stringToBeMatched.Split('_')[numberOfPreviousUnderscores];
```

Comment: sounds good, i will test it